# SolrJ CloudSolrClient incompatible with Hadoop fs Path

Tags: hdfs, oozie, solrj

The goal is to upload index config files from HDFS to Solr via Oozie workflow (Java action).

CloudSolrClient.uploadConfig() accepts a java.nio.file.Paths object in the first parameter.

Running on HDFS (through Oozie launcher), it cannot resolve the config path unless I use org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.

How can I get around this? Is there a version of CloudSolrClient that accepts hadoop.fs.Path as a parameter?

Comment: Can you provide the error message or stack trace of the issue?

Comment: Well there's not a lot to show... either Path [path] does not exist when using java.nio.file.Paths, or java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path cannot be cast to java.nio.file.Path when I try to cast it

Comment: Are you sure that edge node where launcher is running have the java 1.7, because `Paths` class is available from `1.7`.

Comment: Not sure you're seeing the issue... org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient has a method, uploadConfig(Path configPath, String configName), Path is an instance of java.nio.file.Path (ref: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_2_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/CloudSolrClient.html). Running locally works fine, but in prod the filesystem is HDFS, which requires me to use org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path, which this method does not accept.

Comment: You can first download the content from the HDFS and store it locally temporarily (in the launcher) then pass that path to the CloudSolrClient.uploadConfig(). This is a work around I can think of. Thanks.

Comment: This sounds pretty viable... is it possible to load a directory into the workspace? Could I pass a directory path in the <file> parameter?

Comment: If you specify file into `<file>` tag of a action, oozie will localize it into the current directory of the launcher. From there you can use the java file io apis.

Comment: Thanks - adding the directory seems to work... the only weird thing is that uploadConfig doesn't accept the directory path: java.io.IOException: File 'config_directory' exists but is a directory. I know it's a directory... hahaha. Anyway thanks!